# Remove last segment of an URI in Ruby

Tags: ruby, uri

I'm trying to remove the last segment of a given URI using Ruby,

like this:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/?lala=foo
```

How can I get this :

```
"http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/"
```

I've searched and all that I got is to get the last segment or the host part of the URI.

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? What is the error message you are getting? StackOverflow is not a write-my-code-for-me-service. Write-my-code-for-me-services are usually called programmers, and if you need one of those, you can hire one.

Comment: Do you want to remove only the query string or also any possible fragment identifier?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's essential you provide accurate examples of the input data and the related output data for each input. Failing to do that is irritating as your requirements change as you throw a new condition into the mix. As is, it's difficult to tell what you're asking so you need to add a lot of detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment to @JorgWMittag all your really need is this

```
s = 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/?lala=foo#quux'
s[/.*\//]
#=> "http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/"
s = 'http://example.com/foo/bar.html'
s[/.*\//]
#=> "http://example.com/foo/"
```

Basically it just says grab the substring up to the last slash obviously if you have things like

```
s = "http://example.com/foo/bar/?baz=/blah/blah"
```

Then this will not work but your question and specifications seem very loose at the moment.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, sorry if I didn't expose clear my concerns. THANK YOU ALL!

Answer (score 7):

The most important thing to remember is: Ruby is an object-oriented language. It's not an array-oriented language, it's not a hash-oriented language, it's not a string-oriented language.

When you want to do something, you construct an object which represents your concept and manipulate that object. In this case, you want to manipulate a URI, so you need to construct an object which represents a URI.

Thankfully, the Ruby standard library already contains a ready-made class for such objects:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/?lala=foo#quux')

uri.query = nil

uri
# => #<URI::HTTP http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/#quux>

uri.to_s
# => 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/#quux'

uri.fragment = nil

uri
# => #<URI::HTTP http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/>

uri.to_s
# => 'http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/'
```

As you can see, once you create a proper object representing your URI, manipulating it becomes trivial.

Comment: Yes Jörg, I'm having troubles with Ruby trying to achieve things that is not designed to do. But the point is to remove the last segment of differents URI's like:
http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/?lala=foo
http://example.com/foo/bar.html
http://example.com/bar/foo/baz.jar

Comment: @AlvaroGomezFolgado "But the point is to remove the last segment of differents URI's like: example.com/foo/bar/baz/?lala=foo example.com/foo/bar.html example.com/bar/foo/baz.jar" Then your question isn't asked right. Provide samples of the various input data you will see, and the expected output of processing them. That way you don't irritate those helping you by changing the requirements after giving a single example that wasn't a real representation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/?lala=foo"
"http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/?lala=foo"
["http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/", "lala=foo"]
>> s.split("?").first
"http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/"
```

Did you tried something like this, possibly the first thing when you want to split a string

Comment: Hi Bijendra, I tried something like that, but the purpose is not to focus on the "?" character because there is some other URIs that doesn't has the same format

Comment: No, don't use string manipulation. Use the tools designed for the job, such as URI or Addressable::URI.

Comment: oh sorry, possibly i missed the qsn then due to clarity over it